# Facing Issue in Parsing .csv file using Java

Tags: java, csv, datetime, parsing, hashmap

I have a .csv file as below . It has 2 columns `URL` and `timestamp` . Assume URL to be alphanumeric and date/time in UTC.

```
URL,timestamp
URL1,2018-12-09T14:19:00+00:00
URL1,2018-12-09T10:13:00+00:00
URL2,2018-12-09T07:25:00+00:00
URL3,2018-12-09T06:19:00+00:00
URL2,2018-12-08T22:03:00+00:00
URL3,2018-12-08T21:30:00+00:00
URL3,2018-12-08T09:30:00+00:00
URL2,2018-12-07T23:30:00+00:00
```

I want to find for a given Date as input , which URL was visited the most.

```
eg : Input : 2018-12-09
     Output : URL1
    Explaination: We can see above that URL1 has 2 entries on 2018-12-09 ,so it was visited the most times on that day.
```

My idea of achieving above is to use a `HashMap<String , List<String>>` to store the `date as Key` and `URL's as List of values for that Key`.

I'm facing problem with parsing this file. How can I

1. Parse the timestamp column and store the Date as `Key` in the Map ,as there are duplicate dates?
2. I assume once we can narrow down the above ,we can store the URL's as Values inside a List for that Key. We can extract the values for corresponding Key from the map to an Array and then check for most repeating URL. Is this a correct approach ?

I'm not using any 3rd Party libraries for this

Any inputs on the above are highly appreciated .

Comment: Just Google how to read a file using Java line by line.  Pretty straight forward.

Comment: It seems that you're looking for multiset. What if you simply count the number of occurrences of each URL?

Comment: @fluffy We can count the occurrences of URL , but then how can we determine on which day that URL was visited the most ?

Comment: @Dale  Sure . I wanted to just put my logic here and get any suggestions on it .

Comment: In which time zone do you want the date? It is never the same date in all time zones, and midnight (understood as when the date changes) generally happens at different times in different time zones.

Comment: Which part of it are you having trouble with? Please show us your attempt. I voted to close because I can’t tell whether this a question about reading a file, about parsing CSV, about parsing date and time, about extracting a date from a date and time, about finding the most frequent among some values or something else.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you create a custom type e.g. `Visit` as shown below to handle the records in a structured way. You can [use the standard Java I/O library](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html) or some specialized library to read the records from the file and populate the `Visit` objects. I recommend you use the popular [opencsv library](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) for this purpose. Whatever way you populate the `Visit` objects and create a `List<Visit>` of these objects, you can use Java Stream API to process the list. For the sake of this demo, I have manullay created a `List<Visit>` with the records shown in your question.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Visit {
    private String url;
    private OffsetDateTime dateTime;

    public Visit(String url, OffsetDateTime dateTime) {
        this.url = url;
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public OffsetDateTime getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Visit> list = List.of(
                new Visit("URL1", OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-12-09T14:19:00+00:00")),
                new Visit("URL1", OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-12-09T10:13:00+00:00")),
                new Visit("URL2", OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-12-09T07:25:00+00:00")),
                new Visit("URL3", OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-12-09T06:19:00+00:00")),
                new Visit("URL2", OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-12-08T22:03:00+00:00")),
                new Visit("URL3", OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-12-08T21:30:00+00:00")),
                new Visit("URL3", OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-12-08T09:30:00+00:00")),
                new Visit("URL2", OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-12-07T23:30:00+00:00"))

        );

        // Tests
        System.out.println(mostVisitedUrlByDate(list, LocalDate.of(2018, 12, 9)));
        System.out.println(mostVisitedUrlByDate(list, LocalDate.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)));
        System.out.println(mostVisitedUrlByDate(null, LocalDate.of(2018, 12, 9)));
    }

    static String mostVisitedUrlByDate(List<Visit> list, LocalDate date) {
        return list!=null ? list.stream() // Traverse list if it is not null
            .filter(e -> e.getDateTime().toLocalDate().equals(date))
            // Get a Map<String, List<Visit>> where value is the list of Visit objects grouped on the URL
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Visit::getUrl))
                .values()
                // Stream of values of Map obtained as a result of grouping 
                .stream()
                // Find the value i.e. List<Visit> of largest size
                .max(Comparator.comparing(List::size))
                //A List<Visit> with a default Visit object  
                .orElse(List.of(new Visit("Unknown", OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC))))
                // All Visit elements in the value have same URL. Get the URL of the first value
                .get(0) 
                .getUrl()
                // Return "Unknown" if list is null
                :"Unknown";
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
URL1
Unknown
Unknown
```

I have put enough comments in the code to make it easier for you to understand. Additionally, I have put three test calls to the method, `mostVisitedUrlByDate` so that you can understand the purpose of each method call on `Stream` and `Optional` clearly.

Answer (score 1):

I created a CSV file containing the sample data from your question and named it `recorder.csv`.

Using Java [stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) and interface [Multiset](https://guava.dev/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) – from Google [guava](https://github.com/google/guava) library – as suggested by @fluffy in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65750669/facing-issue-in-parsing-csv-file-using-java#comment116251413_65750669).
(Explanations after the code.)

```java
import com.google.common.collect.HashMultiset;
import com.google.common.collect.Multiset;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class MostHits {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate search = LocalDate.parse("2018-12-09", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
        Path path = Paths.get("recorder.csv");

        Supplier<Map<LocalDate, Multiset<String>>> supplier = () -> new HashMap<>();

        BiConsumer<Map<LocalDate, Multiset<String>>, String> accumulator = (map, line) -> {
            String[] flds = line.split(",");
            LocalDate key = LocalDate.parse(flds[1], DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
            Multiset<String> multiset;
            if (map.containsKey(key)) {
                multiset = map.get(key);
            }
            else {
                multiset = HashMultiset.create();
            }
            multiset.add(flds[0]);
            map.put(key, multiset);
        };

        BiConsumer<Map<LocalDate, Multiset<String>>, Map<LocalDate, Multiset<String>>> combiner =
                (map1, map2) -> {};
        try {
            Map<LocalDate, Multiset<String>> map = Files.lines(path)
                                                        .collect(supplier, accumulator, combiner);
            Multiset<String> value = map.get(search);
            if (value != null) {
                Optional<String> most = value.elementSet()
                                             .stream()
                                             .max((s1, s2) -> value.count(s1) - value.count(s2));
                most.ifPresentOrElse(System.out::println,
                                     () -> System.out.println("No max found."));
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("No value for: " + search);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            xIo.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

1. I used an arbitrary search key. You can obtain the search key any way you want, for example accepting a value from the user.
2. I create a `Map` from the lines in the CSV file. The `Map` key is the date field from each line in the CSV file and the `Map` value is a `Multiset` which contains each element once but also contains a count of how many times each element was added to the `Multiset`.
3. After reading the entire file, I get the `Map` value that is associated with the search key.
4. If there is an entry in the `Map` for the search key, I get the element with the highest count from the `Multiset` that is associated with the search key.
5. I print out the URL that got the most hits on the searched for date.